# laravel 5.5 returning null for query params

Tags: laravel

I have a url: `/feedback?page=1` and in my route (not a controller, just a route method) I have the following method inside a route group (the $userId var is from the group prefix):

```
Route::prefix('accounts/{userId}/feedback')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function(Request $request, $userId) {
        die(var_Dump($request->query('page')));
    });
...
}
```

This returns null. I have tried `input('page')` to no success either. What am I blatently doing wrong?

I've also tried `dd($_GET)` which strangely returns nothing.

Comment: the `url` should be `/?page=1`

Comment: @HoàngĐăng not even that is working

Comment: that's strange that's should be working, maybe there's an error before it reach that line , did you try putting `echo "something";` after that line see if it actually reach that line

Comment: there must be some issue with your site configuration on nginx or apache.

Comment: @JigneshSolanki strangely, that's what I wrote as an 'answre' about 5 hours before your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dd($_GET)` not working it led me to investigate whether the server was passing the query string... I looked into the nginx config and I wasn't passing `$query_string` to the index file. So, that's that.

Answer (score 0):

Have to include `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in the beginning.

You can use `dd($request->query('page'))` instead of `die(var_dump())`

Comment: the include is there.

Comment: can you paste all `Route:group`

Comment: updated the question. this route is definitely 'catching' the route.

Comment: it worked for me returned `string(1) "1"`. Are there any error?